# Postion Divs inside a container using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was designing a website. I am having some issue on the Faculties Page. The Issue is as Follows.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want the Div a to reach position b. without changing the responsivity.
(Bootstrap if Possible)

```html
<div class = "row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-start align-content-around">
    
<div class = "item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark col-sm-5 col-xm-5"></div>
<div class = "item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark col-sm-5 col-xm-5"></div>
<div class = "item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark col-sm-5 col-xm-5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should post proper jsfiddle to understand whole problem..you can give css to that div as `position:relative` and `top:150px` or wherever it fits to. Try it if it helps you

Comment: What bootstrap version are you using? Did you have a look at http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with your current markup which is like below...

```css
.item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-start">
  <div class="item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark col-5" style="height:150px;"></div>
  <div class="item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark col-5" style="height:100px;"></div>
  <div class="item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark col-5" style="height:100px;"></div>
  <div class="item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark col-5" style="height:100px;"></div>
</div>
```

You will need to wrap the left and right divs in different div like below...

```css
.item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-start">
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark" style="height:200px;"></div>
    <div class="item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark" style="height:100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark" style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div class="item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark" style="height:100px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try multi classes of row and cols as given below..

```html
<div class = "row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-start align-content-around">     
<div class = "item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark col-sm-5 col-xm-5"></div>
<div class = "item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark col-sm-5 col-xm-5"></div>
  <div class="row"><div class = "item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark col-sm-5 col-xm-5"></div></div>
  <div class="row"><div class = "item text-light wow fadeInUp bg-dark col-sm-5 col-xm-5"></div></div>
</div>
```